# Compounding percentages in standard sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table of budgets with start dates and an assigned budget amount. Each budget also comes with a percentage that is to be rolled over into the following month:

[image]

I want to achieve this output, where the actualized budget is equal to the assigned budget plus the rollover from the previous month. The rollover for each month is calculated based on the actualized budget not the assigned budget:

[image]

I can get as far as calculating the amount to be rolled over from the assigned budget, and getting the accumulated rollover based on the assigned budgets, but I'm stuck on how to apply the rollover percentage to the cumulative amount:

```
WITH budget_data AS (
  SELECT 'a' AS budget, '2021-01-01' AS start_date, 1000 AS assigned, 0.2 AS rollover_percent
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b' AS budget, '2021-02-01' AS start_date, 2000 AS assigned, 0.3 AS rollover_percent
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c' AS budget, '2021-03-01' AS start_date, 1500 AS assigned, 0.15 AS rollover_percent
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'd' AS budget, '2021-04-01' AS start_date, 1300 AS assigned, 0.2 AS rollover_percent
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'e' AS budget, '2021-05-01' AS start_date, 1700 AS assigned, 0.1 AS rollover_percent
)
SELECT
  budget,
  start_date,
  assigned,
  rollover_percent,
  assigned * rollover_percent AS rollover_on_assigned,
  SUM(assigned * rollover_percent) OVER (ORDER BY start_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS prior_rollover_on_assigned
FROM
  budget_data AS bd
```

Comment: I'm not understanding what is your question

Comment: I've edited to add the desired output - does that help?

Comment: You need a recursive query. AFAIK Bigquery has LOOP for that.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below solution

```
with arrays as (
  select 
    array_agg(assigned order by start_date) aa,
    array_agg(rollover_percent order by start_date) bb
  from budget_data
), temp as (
  select *, row_number() over(order by start_date) pos
  from budget_data
), temp2 as (
  select *,
    array(
      select b 
      from arrays, unnest(bb) b with offset bpos
      where bpos < pos  
      order by bpos
    ) bbb
  from temp
)
select budget, start_date, assigned, rollover_percent, 
  (
    select as struct 
      round(sum(a * bb) / rollover_percent, 2) as actualized,
      round(sum(a * bb), 2) as rollover
    from (
      select a, exp(sum(ln(b))) bb
      from arrays, unnest(aa) a with offset apos,
      unnest(bbb) b with offset bpos 
      where apos < pos
      and bpos >= apos
      group by a
    )
  ).*
from temp2
```

if applied to sample data in y our question - output is

[image]

Note: above is implementation of mathematical expression of value of `rollover` -

[image]

where `A` is value of `assigned`
and `B` is value of `rollover_percent`